# None Shared member requires an object reference

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem because I changed my code from `vb6` to `.net` and I cant seem to sort out this issue I am having. Please assist.

The error message I'm getting:

```
Error 5 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

This is happening quite a few places in the code. This is my code. The problem is where it says FrmInvItem.Inv.`

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
 Public Class ClsInv

```
Public Function RunProcess(ByVal ConnectStr As String, ByRef Parstr As String) As Integer
    Dim frmInvIt As frmInvItem
    RunProcess = frmInvItem.Inv(ConnectStr, Parstr)
    frmInvIt.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: So you're using VB.Net, not C#? If so, change your question's tag.

Comment: Your frmInvIt needs to be initialized, by using New keyword: Dim frmInvIt As New frmInvItem

Comment: Thanks allot Lucky3 seems to have sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `Inv` is not shared, but you are calling it without an instance of the class in which it is. So you either have to make it `shared` or create an instance of `frmInvItem`:

```
Dim frmInvIt As New frmInvItem() ' create instance
RunProcess = frmInvIt.Inv(ConnectStr, Parstr) ' use it on this instance
```

`frmInvItem` is the class, you can call a method via classname only if the method is [`shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> `Shared` procedures are class methods that are not associated with a
>   specific instance of a class. For example, the `Cos` method defined
>   within the `Math` class is a shared method. You can call a shared
>   procedure as a method of an object or directly from the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a method called Inv on a the `frmInvIt` without creating an instance.

You should create an instance to run your method against:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx